# Where can I find the Blacksmith from Silverton?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm trying to retrieve Gwent Cards, but cannot seem to find this one "Blacksmith" from "Silverton". He's nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 4):

While searching for a solution, I came across [this guide](http://www.gosunoob.com/witcher-3/gwent-players-merchants/) that lists the locations of all Gwent players in The Witcher 3.

I believe you're looking for this blacksmith:

> The blacksmith in Silverton, north-west of Hierarch Square

Thus, your blacksmith is northwest of Hierarch Square, in Novigrad. Here is a map of Novigrad:

[image: hierarch square]

In addition, from [this site](http://guides.gamepressure.com/thewitcher3/guide.asp?ID=30742), you can also see the locations of different merchants located in Novigrad and I believe the blacksmith you're looking for is labeled "Blacksmith (1)".

> [image: merchant locations]